# Flutter/Dart/Android - App Crashes after Allowing Permissions

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm using the `Flutter Audio Recorder` plugin in my app. Apparently, there's a problem when requesting more than one permission at the same time in Android.

In my case, upon the first build of my app, a popup appears and asks "Allow myapp to access photos and media on your device?". I click allow and then another popup appears which asks "allow myapp to record audio?". After clicking this 2nd allow, the app crashes. When I rebuild the app again, this time the popups don't appear and the app works fine.

I'm not sure where to find the problem. Here's what's in my AndroidManifest.xml;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

And here's the code I'm using to access the `Flutter Audio Recorder` plugin. (I got this code from an example in the Github repository for the plugin);

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _init();
  super.initState();
   }

  _init() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        stopButton = false;
        playButton = false;
        recButton = true;
      });
      if (await FlutterAudioRecorder.hasPermissions) {
        String customPath = '/flutter_audio_recorder_';
        io.Directory appDocDirectory;
        if (io.Platform.isIOS) {
          appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        } else {
          appDocDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        }
        customPath = appDocDirectory.path +
            customPath +
            DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        _recorder = FlutterAudioRecorder(customPath,
            audioFormat: AudioFormat.AAC, sampleRate: 44100);

        await _recorder.initialized;
        var current = await _recorder.current(channel: 0);

         setState(() {
          _current = current;
          _currentStatus = current.status;
        });
      } else {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
             SnackBar(content:  Text("You must accept permissions")));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And here's the `hasPermissions`  method from within the `flutter_audio_recorder.dart` plugin itself;

```
static Future<bool> get hasPermissions async {
    bool hasPermission = await _channel.invokeMethod('hasPermissions');
    return hasPermission;
  }
```

Here's what I get in my Android studio console when the app builds and before I click "allow" in the first popup;

```
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): handleHasPermission false
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): handleHasPermission false
W/Activity(21727): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): parsing result
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): onRequestPermissionsResult -true
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): handleHasPermission false
W/Activity(21727): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): parsing result
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): onRequestPermissionsResult -true
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): handleHasPermission false
W/Activity(21727): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): parsing result
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): onRequestPermissionsResult -true
```

And here's what I get when clicking the 2nd allow;

```
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): parsing result
D/AndroidAudioRecorder(21727): onRequestPermissionsResult -true
D/AndroidRuntime(21727): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(21727): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21727): Process: com.megleechin.speakoholic, PID: 21727
E/AndroidRuntime(21727): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.megleechin.speakoholic/com.megleechin.speakoholic.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:238)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at com.zeno.flutter_audio_recorder.FlutterAudioRecorderPlugin.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterAudioRecorderPlugin.java:79)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:364)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:579)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivity.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8289)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8139)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
E/AndroidRuntime(21727):    ... 11 more
I/Process (21727): Sending signal. PID: 21727 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Any idea where it's going wrong? Is there a better way I can ask for permissions in my app?

Comment: Hey I am facing the same issue , how did you fix this?

Comment: I used the permissions plugin.

Comment: I am also using permission_handler but still getting same issue

Comment: I was using this https://pub.dev/packages/permissions_plugin but I suspect its now out of date. My app has been on hold for a while so I can't check whether its working.